# Do I have to use the Raspberry PI Kernel version of Alpine Linux?

Tags: boot-issues, kernel, alpine

I want to install Alpine Linux on my Raspberry Pi 3B+.
I know how to install linux via Rufus and have read the wiki on how to install it.
There are 2 different versions of Alpine Linux, one "standard" and one called "Raspberry Pi".

My question:
Am I missing out on performance or compatibility if I choose the Standard version for ARM?

The Raspberry Pi version is in a tar format and won't boot for me.
I also can't create a bootable device via rufus because it is in .tar format.
The wiki hasn't been helpful for that as they only state "it worked with rufus", neither the type of alpine used nor the exact method are documented.

Best Regards,

Chris

Comment: *"I also can't create a bootable device via rufus because it is in .tar format."* ->  Sounds like your real question here is how you are supposed to use it.  If you cannot, then there isn't really a question because there isn't a second option.

Comment: My question still is: Am i missing something if i take the "Standard" version of Alpine for my raspberry?

Comment: I'd guess yes you will miss stuff, but I'm not an alpine user and don't know what images you are referring to.  If it is a stock ARM distro it may not work at all.  Beyond that, if it does, it depends what you want to do with the Pi -- eg., you may or may not get use of the GPIO and camera port.